# Parse json with multiple double quotes c#

Tags: c#, json

Im not sure how to explain the situation so i'll start with an example:

```
    {"SearchData":[{"TOTAL":"1", "RESULT":[{"Id":"/home/solr/example.pdf", 
    "Title":"Whatever", "Extract":"Mr. Dummy ” random text " more random text 
    " " lalal" ", "Content":"", "Author":"Me" }]}]}
```

Im using the Json.net library. The main problem is that I have to parse a Json that includes a random number of double quotes inside of the "Extract" field.

I receive this from a webservice that consults a solr database. Im just programming the front end of this application so it would be better if there is a local solution to this (without modifying the webservice or solr).

I know that if I include a \ before every double quote it will work, but I dont really know how to do that optimally, so it will be slow and considering that I can receive a lot of results, it will slow down the system.

So, is there any way to create a JObject given this situation?

Comment: *"The main problem is that I have to parse a Json that includes a random number of double quotes inside of the "Extract" field."* No, the main problem is that you're being asked to parse invalid JSON. The solution is to require valid JSON. Anything else is guessing where strings start and end.

Comment: That isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @CSharpie the example JSON still fails validation.

Comment: @CSharpie: One of them is. The others aren't.

Comment: The quote before `random text` is ok, the quote after, and the quotes around `lalal` aren't. As @T.J.Crowder states, this is not valid JSON. Using a JSON library to parse it won't work. In short, if this is the data you're getting from the webservice, then that webservice has a bug, it is not producing JSON data. Most likely this is a result of simple string concatenation to build up the JSON result, instead of using a proper JSON library to create the correct result.

Comment: Alright guys thanks a lot!!. Im kinda new to Json so I wasnt sure if it was my lack of knowledge or an invalid format. Thank you all for the fast answers :)